# rpm build with local Required: some_local_package.rpm

Tags: yum, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

`Requires:` in the spec files sets the package dependencies, but what will happen if the repo of the requirements is not in the `repolist`?

Is there a way to use pre downloaded rpm files and tell the `rpmbuild` that the dependencies should be installed from the local file like yum `localinstall`.

Comment: You say you want to tell `rpmbuild` but then in a comment below it implies you meant `rpm` - are you talking about "what you need to do to build an RPM" or "what the end user needs to do to install a set of RPMs?"

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating `rpm` and `yum` when you mention `repolist`.

- `rpm` is a lower level and only knows about RPM files
- `yum` collects sets of RPMs into repositories and sits on top of RPM to handle dependencies

Now, to answer the question - `rpmbuild` does *not* need anything from the `Requires` field to build the RPM. If it does, then the RPMs should be listed as `BuildRequires` in the specfile and only be in `Requires` if the *end user* needs it to be installed to run the *final product*. For example, to build you might need `foo-devel` but at runtime you only need `libfoo`. Those should be declared appropriately.

Even if you fix the `Requires` vs. `BuildRequires` fields, it still won't help you - `rpmbuild` cannot install RPMs itself because **you should *never* run `rpmbuild` as root**. An error in a specfile can *very easily* nuke an entire machine if it's run as root.

Comment: as I understand BuildRequires is used to define the packaged that rpmbuild needs during the installation, a compiler for example. My problem is eliminating the need of adding  yum private repository before installing the Required: package. I other words I have the rpm files, can I pack those in a wrapper rpm package.

Comment: Yes, `BuildRequires` is used to tell `rpmbuild` what packages you need to _build_ the RPM, not _install_ the RPM which is what you do on a target machine. Your original question is talking about telling `rpmbuild` - not `rpm`. No, you cannot put RPM files into another RPM because the `rpm` process is non-reentrant. You need to wrap them all up in a tarball with a shell script for the end user.